# Can __radd__ work with the operands in any order?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I want my `Fraction` class to work as a float when it's being added to floats or integers so I can naturally perform operations with it, but it's only working when the `Fraction` is the rightmost operand. Is there a way to make it work with the operands in any order or should I override another method that I haven't learned of?

Code (I guess variable names are pretty self-explanatory):

```
def __radd__(self,target):
    if type(target) == int or type(target) == float:
        return target + self.num/self.den
```

`1 + Fraction(1,2)` returns `1.5` as it should but `Fraction(1,2) + 1` raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/programming/python/fraction.py", line 86, in <module>
    print(my_fraction + 1)
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/programming/python/fraction.py", line 28, in __add__
    new_den = self.den * target.den
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'den'
```

Comment: If you'd like this class to work on Python 2, you will need to convert self.num &/or self.den to float, eg, `return target + float(self.num)/self.den`. FWIW, in my Fraction class I promote ints to fractions, but I guess it's easy enough for the user to explicitly convert ints themself. BTW, if you want to convert floats to rational form you can use [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Calculating_continued_fraction_representations) techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`__radd__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) only applies to when you do `value + self`.  If you want to handle `self + value`, you need to overload the [`__add__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__).

Since they both do the same thing, you can just do:

```
def __add__(self, target):
    if isinstance(target, (int, float)):
        return target + self.num/self.den
__radd__ = __add__
```

An easy way to remember this is to treat the `r` in `__radd__` as standing for "right".  So, you use `__radd__` when your class is on the right of the `+` operator.

Also, you'll notice that I used [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to do the typechecking.  Aside from being cleaner, this way is preferred by most Python programmers and is explicitly advocated in [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly! Good data on `isinstance` too, I didn't know about it.