# __radd__ function in python and return statement

Tags: python

I am an absolute beginner in Python. I am trying to wrap my head around `__radd__` function. I read [Can __radd__ work with the operands in any order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586663/can-radd-work-with-the-operands-in-any-order) and understand that `radd` is used to tell the operator that "my object is on the right-hand side". The issue is that for one of the code snippets below (adopted from Lutz' Learning Python Book), `radd` throws a `RecursionError`.

```
class Commuter3:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __add__(self, other):
        print('add', self.val, other)
        return self.val + other
    def __radd__(self, other):
        print('radd was called') 
        return other + self #this return statement is problematic
```

Now, let's see whether `__radd__` is able to add the two objects.

```
#Testing
x3 = Commuter3(13)
y3 = Commuter3(23)
x3+y3
```

Here's the output

```
...RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Here's the expected output: I got this by changing `return other + self` to `return self + other`

```
add 13 <__main__.Commuter3 object at 0x0000014B329E74A8>
radd was called
add 23 13
Out[64]: 36
```

Can someone please explain why that return statement throws stack overflow error? How could I mitigate it? I believe I am missing some concept here. Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: It doesn't throw a stack overflow error. The thing is, you're supposed to specify some operation on the attributes and return a new object.

Comment: Something like this: `return Commuter3(self.val + other.val)`

Comment: Since `+` is overwridden with `__radd__` you head into infinite recursion.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: It does throw a recursion error.  Your linked duplicate doesn't answer the question being asked here (although I bet there is a duplicate for it out there somewhere).  It's true that the user might want to wrap the result in the class, but that's not what's being asked here.

Comment: Should it not be `return self + other` to convert right adds to left adds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `other + self`, your object is again on the right-hand side of the add, so `__radd__` is again called.  This calls `__radd__` yet again, and so on.  (`__add__` delegates back to `__radd__` for these nested calls because the left-hand operand is an int.)

Perhaps you meant to do `other + self.val`,as you did in `__add__`?  As cOLDsPEED suggested, you might also want to wrap the return value in your class, a la `return Commuter3(other + self.val)`, otherwise the result of adding two Commuter3 objects will be an int, which often is not what you want.  But that is a separate issue.

Comment: `other + self` may be better than `other + self.val` though.

Comment: @VadimPushtaev: That won't work because of the issue that the question is asking about.

Comment: @BrenBarn `other + self` works for me, but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Damn, i meant `self + other`, so `__add__` is called.